# Why does the loss explode during training from scratch? - Tensorflow Object Detection Models

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

First of all I want to state out that I am familiar with the benefits of transfer learning. Moreover I am able to train a pretrained model from 'modelzoo' on my dataset. But for research purposes I want to train my model from scratch without transferlearning.

I want to adopt the Faster-RCNN Resnet 101 implementation from tensorsflow's Object Detection API to my dataset. If I use one of the pretrained models the training goes as expected and the loss is always in 'normal' ranges (never above about 6). But if I do not use transferlearning the loss jumps very frequently to extrem high values (about 80,000,000), but between those values the loss is in normal ranges. In addition to this I do not see any predictions of the network on images in TensorBoard. It seems like the network does not make any predictions at all. The only thing which I change is to comment out those two lines in the model.config file:

```
 # fine_tune_checkpoint: 'path'
 # from_detection_checkpoint: true
```

I tried a lot of things to find the reason: Changed optimizer, changed the learning rate, used gradient clipping, changed the initializer used different machines to train on but nothing helps. Moreover I inspected my label_map as well as my record file. To ensure that those files are correct I redid the steps mentioned above by using the pascal voc dataset,  the script to create records and the label map from the api, but even with this code from the Object Detection API without any code changes, the loss explodes ([Tensorflow Object Detection API own inputs](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/preparing_inputs.md)).